# Find latest date value in a dictionary

Tags: python, json, datetime, dictionary, python-datetime

I have this code that requests the information of the stock MSFT (Microsoft), the request goes right and i get all the data i need on it, however it i want to get the latest stock price (in python it sorts it out latest to oldest however i do not want to take the data off the top because some languages do not sort it out for me) in the result given below, there are multiple dates eg:

`{u'2019-10-08':`

Now i want to find the latest date in the json data and print THAT out.

I am using Alpha advantage to get this data, there is nothing wrong with the given data.

```
import requests,json

func = 'function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY'
sym = 'symbol=MSFT'
inter = 'interval=10min'
apikey = 'apikey=**********'
url = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?'+func+'&'+sym+'&'+inter+'&'+apikey

resp = requests.get(url)
data = json.loads(resp.content)
d = data['Time Series (Daily)']

# print (d['2020-01-03']) #<- date
# print (max(d.values()))  # does not give the expected data (i think because the date is in a string)

print (d)
```

Shortened Result:

```
{u'Meta Data': {u'1. Information': u'Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes', u'4. 
Output Size': u'Compact', u'5. Time Zone': u'US/Eastern', u'2. Symbol': u'MSFT', u'3. Last 
Refreshed': u'2020-01-03'}, u'Time Series (Daily)': {u'2019-10-08': {u'5. volume': u'26783336',
 u'4. close': u'135.6700', u'2. high': u'137.7600', u'1. open': u'137.0800', u'3. low': u'135.6200'}}
```

I have looked through many answers and some of them unanswered or few in different languages, I have spend some time trying to get the solution to this.

Comment: Try sorted method on doctionary

Comment: @VikasSharma I tried, i need extensive help on that, it did not work for me!

Comment: I once had data like u'123' like you. I found a workaround with django.utils.encoding.smart_str.

Comment: Please share code with sorted

Comment: You want `d[max(d)]` not `max(d.values())` if the dates are the keys.  Otherwise `d.values()` returns the values themselves, so you're asking what is the max of the values which in this case is meaningless.

Comment: @VikasSharma okay give me a second

Comment: @Iguananaut wow it worked~! Thank you so much :D, can you put in an answer, i really want to mark you correct, for any people looking for an answer to this ;)

Comment: That's okay, I don't think it's a very interesting answer since this was just a basic conceptual mistake.

Comment: i'm kinda new to python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you could do the following using [`datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime). Note that in your case, as @Iguananaut pointed out, the date format is in lexicographical order, so you could just use `maxdate = max(d)`.

```
from datetime import datetime

maxdate = max((x for x in d.keys()), key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d"))

print(maxdate)
print(d[maxdate])
```

Which gives me output:

```
2020-01-03
{'1. open': '158.3200',
 '2. high': '159.9450',
 '3. low': '158.0600',
 '4. close': '158.6200',
 '5. volume': '21121681'}
```

Comment: This is not even necessary since if the dates are in YYYY-mm-dd format they are already lexicographically ordered.

Comment: I updated my answer to reference this and provide a solution without `datetime`  - I think it's still worth including the `datetime` solution though.